# Commanding arduino over serial only works while tailing

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I have the following arduino code:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

char rfSetting[6]  = "01111";

String command;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Transmitter is connected to Arduino Pin #10  
  mySwitch.enableTransmit(10);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // get incoming byte:
    command = Serial.readString();
    command.trim();
    if( command.length() == 2 && 
        command[0] > 64 && command[0] < 69 &&
       (command[1] == '0' | command[1] == '1')){
          char rfCommand[6] = "00000";
          rfCommand[command[0]-65] = '1';
          Serial.println(rfCommand);
          if(command[1] == '0') {
            mySwitch.switchOff(rfSetting, rfCommand);
          } else {
            mySwitch.switchOn(rfSetting, rfCommand);
          }
          delay(1000);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Invalid Input");
    }
  }
}
```

To command the arduino I use the following python script:

```
import serial
import sys
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
time.sleep(2)
ser.write(sys.argv[1])
ser.close()
```

Now when I execute the python script with:

```
python test.py A0
```

nothing happens. If I run this

```
tail -f /dev/ttyACM0
```

in parallel, it works.

I am trying to send commands to the arduino without tailing the port.
What am I doing wrong?

Host OS: Raspian

PS: I have already tried to solve it with this:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 9600 cs8 cread clocal
```

but this doesn't help.

Comment: does serial need `flush`ing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
import serial
import sys
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",9600)
time.sleep(2)
ser.write(sys.argv[1]) 
ser.flush()   # THIS here should put the data through, 
              # might block until your os decides to put the data through 
ser.close()
```

You might also take this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40438103/7505395 hints into cosideration

Comment: Herzlichen Dank :)

Comment: @user547995  gern geschehen